# CSS IE8 and invisible top of H2

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

On this site ( http://test.photoline.nl/biografie/ ) I have a Header2 (Biografie). When using IE8 (normal mode) the top of the header is not visible or disappears when the mouse is moved over the page.

I really have no idea why. CSS is not part of my core knowledge, so maybe there is a simple fix for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because of using a webfont. Sometimes they get clipped in older browsers. Try modifying the `line-height` of the `<h2>`:

```
h2 { line-height: 16px; }
```

I would also suggest using a CSS reset like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css).